# INSERT INTO SELECT - large amount of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I want to insert records into a TempTable. Something like this:

```
insert into ##tempT
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

MyTable contains a large amount of records so the "insert into" takes a long time.

If I try to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##tempT
```

it returns always "0" until all records from "MyTable" are inserted by INSERT INTO command.

How can I get a progress count that advise me how many records are in ##tempT?

I need to update a progress bar value while the SQL command is running.

Thank you.

Comment: out of curiosity why would you insert data into a temp table?

Answer (score 8):

try

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##tempT
```

Comment: Good point, or better still: `select count(*) from ##TempT with (nolock)` to avoid affecting the connection state.

Comment: Both `read uncommited` and `nolock` will work in your scenario. However, they are both dangerous weapons, so refrain from using them in data manipulating scenarios (a progress bar is ok).

Comment: Okay, I just tried using the with nolock method to see how far along an insert statement I was running had gotten (it was inserting about 26 mil rows).  Even with nolock it came back as 0 every time.

Comment: how are you doing this test? try running your insert on one tab in SSMS and running the count on another. It should work I just did a test here to be sure

Answer (score 1):

You can split your query up.

```
x = number of records in MyTable / 100
i = 0

do until we're done
    queryString = "insert into ##tempT "
    queryString += "select top " + x " + " * FROM MyTable "
    queryString += "where RecordNumber > " + i

    Execute queryString
    Update Progress Bar
    i = i + x
loop
```

You'll notice that you'll need some sort of RecordNumber field to make this work though.  There are various ways to accomplish that you can search for.

Comment: Ben's solution (comment on Diego's answer) is probably the best for your particular scenario.  My solution is a lot better when you're confined to a single thread and that thread is doing the DB updating and the GUI feedback like we generally had to do back in the vb6 days.

Comment: This is an awful solution for today standards.

Comment: @JotaBe Well now that just hurts my feelings.  Sorry my answer didn't please you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure and DECLARE a variable COUNT and treat this as a looping variable and each time an insert is done, increment COUNT by 1 and keep printing it using another query whenever you want to know the count .Or, return this count from the procedure and read it into your program for updating the progress bar. :)

Comment: You can also keeping recording it in a queue and then later pushing it as a transaction to the DB table incase you donot need to update it in TempTable immediately.It can improve performance and can be done offline too.

Comment: the insert is being done in one batch. this solution wont work

Comment: It's about inserting into the queue not a table.

Comment: yes but when would you do that if the main insert is being done on one go